# Why is a DispatcherTimer Tick event not occurring on time?

Tags: c#

I want to disable a button *-to prevent double click: On a tablet PC you push once, it clicked twice and this is the easiest hack that I know-* for a short period but I noticed/debugged the interval might be too long in practice; 50 ms vs > 2 seconds.

There is in only one line starts the timer and one line stops it. Randomly the interval is 50 ms or much bigger. There is no CPU consume, I just click the button with mouse on my 4 core desktop PC.

What would be the reason?

```
    DispatcherTimer timerTouchDelay = new DispatcherTimer();

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //Init
        if (timerTouchDelay.Interval.Milliseconds == 0)
        {
            timerTouchDelay.Tick += new EventHandler(timerTouchDelay_Tick);
            timerTouchDelay.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 50); //ms

        }


        if(timerTouchDelay.IsEnabled)
            return;

        timerTouchDelay.Start();

        HandleKeyDown();
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
    }

    private void timerTouchDelay_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timerTouchDelay.Stop();
    }
```

Comment: Can't you just disable it in the OnMouseDown function and Enable it on the first timerTouchDelay_Tick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand why this is the case, I would highly recommend the following article:

[Comparing the Timer Classes in the .NET Framework Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx)

For reference, `DispatcherTimer` is very similar to `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, for which the author states "If you're looking for a metronome, you've come to the wrong place". This timer is not designed to 'tick' at exact intervals.

Comment: I think I need to replace all DispatcherTimers in my code, in a slow PC, the application acts different. But it's a huge difference between 50 ms and ~1++ seconds...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of running a timer, why not just record the time at which the button was last pressed. If it's more than 50 milliseconds ago, go ahead and perform the action, otherwise just exit.

```
DateTime lastMouseDown = DateTime.MinValue;

protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if(DateTime.Now.Subtract(lastMouseDown).TotalMilliseconds < 50)
       return;
    lastMouseDown = DateTime.Now;

    HandleKeyDown();
    base.OnMouseDown(e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, it works much solid. VB6 like static variables would be nice at the moment...